# MvxException: Failed to resolve type...IRepository

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, xamarin, mvvmcross

In our `MvxApplication`, I'm using the `EndingWith` method to register our Repositories.

I used this approach in a different project where our App.cs and our Repositories were in the same project, and everything worked properly. Now that I've moved the App.cs into a separate project, the MvvmCross IOC doesn't register the dependencies from our core app.

The initialize method

```
public override void Initialize() {

    // stuff happens here

    // Register all repositories
    CreatableTypes().EndingWith("Repository").AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();

    // more stuff happens here

    // Resolve the DbVersionRepo to run migrations.
    // This line is breaking
    var databaseVersionRepository = MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Instance.Resolve < IDatabaseVersionRepository > ();

}
```

The repository in question

```
public class DatabaseVersionRepository : RepositoryBase, IDatabaseVersionRepository
{ 
    // do stuff
}
```

The Exception

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to resolve type OurApp.AppCore.Repositories.IDatabaseVersionRepository
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043): 
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043): Unhandled Exception:
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043): Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to resolve type OurApp.AppCore.Repositories.IDatabaseVersionRepository
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve[IDatabaseVersionRepository] () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043):   at OurApp.CustomApp.Core.App.Initialize () [0x00135] in c:\Projects\OurApp\OurApp.Droid\App.cs:63 
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.CreateAndInitializeApp (IMvxPluginManager pluginManager) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeApp (IMvxPluginManager pluginManager) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeSecondary () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
12-10 10:35:43.275 E/mono    (24043):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.<InitializeFromSplashScreen>b__5 (System.Object ignored) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The project structure is something like this.

```text
OurCompany.AppCore
    \ Repositories
        \IDatabaseVersionRepository.cs
        \DatabaseVersionRepository.cs

OurCompany.CustomApp.Core
    \ App.cs

OurCompany.CustomApp.Droid.Ui
    \ Setup.cs
```

I should also note that I tried this approach but got the same results.

```
CreatableTypes().Inherits<IDatabaseVersionRepository>().AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

Comment: See 'bulk registration by convention' in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control - includes non-core assembly example

Comment: @stuart Oh, that's great. Didn't find that on my first read. What would it take to have `.InNamespace("MyApp.Core.HyperSpace")` access external DLL's instead of having to use a Type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Stuart's comment above, the way to resolve dependencies that live outside the current assembly is to do the following.

```
typeof(RepositoryBase).Assembly
                      .CreatableTypes()
                      .EndingWith("Repository")
                      .AsInterfaces()
                      .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```